# collision between RB and softbody objects?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, soft-body, collision

I have been trying to get a wrecking ball to collide with an upright slab of jello, with no success so far.  I've tried so many combinations of physics attributes that I can't remember them all, but so far I have achieved only 2 main types of result:  1) the wrecking ball hits the jello slab and is stopped dead, 2) the wrecking ball goes right through the jello slab.  What I expected:  the slab would cave in at the impact point, quiver and wobble, and be hurled backwards.

I believe the jello slab is more or less correct because I drop it a short distance at start of sim and it compresses and bounces back convincingly.  So I think there is something about collisions between RB objects and SB objects that I'm not understanding.  Can someone point me at the tute or example that I have not yet found by googling?

UPDATE:  One way to do it (sorta):  create a rigid body.  Then add Soft Body to it and proceed to tweak.
https://www.flickr.com/photos/rootlessagrarian/31909036596
I hope that link is visible to others.  Anyway, as (I hope) you can see it is semi-successful, but the "jello mattress" continues to have a life of its own after impact, slithering towards the edge of the floor and remaining obstinately dimpled in places even though Plastic was set to 0.  Also, the observant viewer will notice that the wrecking ball and chain actually penetrate the surface on impact :-(  but it's the best I have managed thus far.  I did try making the wrecking ball a very stiff Soft Body, but then of course it wouldn't stick to the chain... I'd have had to redo the entire chain.

Here is another probably final attempt with even stranger physics.  In this one I went back and adjusted centre of mass for the wrecking ball, made sure to Apply all Scales, and gave the jello mattress a plinth so it could be knocked off.

[image]

I have no idea why it is hesitating on its way to the floor... suggestions welcome, though I may soon give up on trying to make these two species of object interact and move on to learning more about things that Blender *wants* to do rather than trying to make it do things it doesn't like.

Comment: This kind of thing is better done with dynamic paint instead of soft bodies.

Comment: Can you (or someone) expand a little on that?  Dynamic paint won't allow the whole mesh to bend, as far as I understand it... whereas I was hoping for a real bend, flex, wobble effect, kind of a trampoline look.  Are collisions between HB and SB objects problematic?

Comment: It allows a whole mesh to bend, if in the Canvas, you set the Surface type to Wave. Another possibility would be to use two soft bodies, but one with high stiffness settings.

Comment: I tried Waves in Dynamic Paint but alas, the target object then has no Collision attributes;  it doesn't collide with the wrecking ball and fall over.  The impact wave is nice, but no other physics... if I try to add rigid body, then I lose the dynamic paint effect;  it appears the two are mutually exclusive...

Comment: I know no easy way to combine the two, but there are always tricks. For example before the collision change from rigid body physics to keyframe animation and then change back. Or there is the "everything softbody" solution, as I wrote before.

Comment: I tried embedding a collision plane w/in the dynamic paint object, then parenting the DP object to the collision plane.  this was hopeful at first -- they absorb the impact and fall over together nicely -- but the embedded plane seems to damp the wave effect, not sure why, so there is very little wobbling.  also of course the DP object doesn't interact properly with the floor after falling.  I didn't expect RB and SB physics to be so dissociated :-)  I can see now that this is a "clever workaround needed" situation and probably beyond my n00by powers.  ta for the suggestions!

Comment: I just noticed your video on flickr, I think it is pretty good, apart from the timing: the ball moves slowly, suggesting a large object, but the  "jello mattress" moves fast, suggesting a smaller object.

Comment: lbalazscs (are you with SCS?  I am a huge fan of ETS2, it's the whole reason I'm getting into 3d modelling) I am interested in your timing remark but I think it warrants a new question...

Comment: What makes you think I'm with SCS? No, but at least I answered your other question :)

Comment: username ended in scs... just a stray thought...  and thanks for the other answer!

Comment: https://www.flickr.com/photos/rootlessagrarian/32070780755/

latest version if anyone is still interested:  improving a bit but the jello object still falls at weirdly inconsistent rates, as if it had very little mass and huge air resistance...