# timing in physics simulations: per scene or per object?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, soft-body

In ref to a previous question
[collision between RB and softbody objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69920/collision-between-rb-and-softbody-objects)
lbalazscs kindly remarked *I just noticed your video on flickr, I think it is pretty good, apart from the timing: the ball moves slowly, suggesting a large object, but the "jello mattress" moves fast, suggesting a smaller object.*

This causes me to ask, is it actually possible to have 2 objects (interacting!) in a physics simulation, and have them running on different clocks, i.e. deliberately slowing down one object to give it the illusion of greater mass rather than just adding mass to its physical properties.  I thought there was only one master clock for the whole physics world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different simulations can run at different speeds, there is no one "master clock", which is a good thing, because you can control separately the speed of your simulations.

For rigid bodies, the speed setting is under [Properties Editor/Scene/Rigid Body World](https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/rigid_body/world.html)

Similarly, soft bodies and cloth have a speed setting under the Physics tab. For fluids and smoke you set the simulation speed in their domain objects, also under the the Physics tab. For fluid simulations, also see the question [For Fluid Simulation, what do the Start, End and Speed settings mean?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5072/for-fluid-simulation-what-do-the-start-end-and-speed-settings-mean)

Dynamic Paint canvases where the surface type is *Waves* have [two speed settings](https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/dynamic_paint/canvas.html):

> **Timescale** Directly adjusts simulation speed without affecting simulation outcome. Lower values make simulation go slower and otherwise.
>
> **Speed** Affects how fast waves travel on the surface. This setting is also corresponds to the size of the simulation. Half the speed equals surface double as large.